Flutter DataTable headingRowColor using WidgetStateColor does not work properly
Code: I built a DataTable widget and I would like to change the header color of the table by the following:
headingRowColor: WidgetStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
                    if (states.contains(WidgetState.pressed)) {
                      return Colors.red;
                    } else if (states.contains(WidgetState.hovered)) {
                      return Colors.blue;
                    } else {
                      return Colors.white;
                    }
                  }),

Problem:
The problem with the code above is that the color always becomes Colors.white as shown in the picture below where my cursor is hovering above the heading row (shown by tooltip is where my cursor is).

The color stays with Colors.white when it should have been Colors.blue.
Observations:
I've also noticed that if I set Colors.white into Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5), when I hover the widget, the color correctly changes according to the states, but it becomes transparent which I do not want.
Question:
How do I change the header color of DataTable then?

If you need to change color on pressed then you need to use GestureDetector or InkWell and if you need to hovering then you need to use MouseRegion Widget
For pressed I have used below Properties
onTapDown : tap with a primary button has contacted the screen at a particular location.
onTapUp:  trigger a tap with a primary button has stopped contacting the screen at a particular location.
onTapCancel: previously triggered onTapDown will not end up causing a tap.
For Hovered I have used below Properties
onEnter: Triggered when a mouse pointer has entered this widget.
onExit: Triggered when a mouse pointer has exited this widget when the widget is still mounted.
Full Example:
class DataTableExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataTableExampleState createState() => _DataTableExampleState();
}

class _DataTableExampleState extends State<DataTableExample> {
  bool isHoverState = false;
  bool isPressedState = false;

  void onHoverState(bool isHovering) {
    setState(() {
      isHoverState = isHovering;
    });
  }

  void onPressState(bool isPressing) {
    setState(() {
      isPressedState = isPressing;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) => onPressState(true),
      onTapUp: (_) => onPressState(false),
      onTapCancel: () => onPressState(false),
      child: MouseRegion(
        onEnter: (_) => onHoverState(true),
        onExit: (_) => onHoverState(false),
        child: DataTable(
          headingRowColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
            (Set<WidgetState> states) {
              if (isPressedState) return Colors.red;
              if (isHoverState) return Colors.blue;
              return Colors.transparent; // default color
            },
          ),
          columns: [
            DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Age')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Role')),
          ],
          rows: const <DataRow>[
            DataRow(
              cells: <DataCell>[
                DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                DataCell(Text('19')),
                DataCell(Text('Student')),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: <DataCell>[
                DataCell(Text('Janine')),
                DataCell(Text('43')),
                DataCell(Text('Professor')),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: <DataCell>[
                DataCell(Text('William')),
                DataCell(Text('27')),
                DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Result Screens:
On Normal: 
On Hovered: 
On Pressed: 

Hello, thank you for your response. I've tried the sample code you provided, however, I was looking for color changes per column instead of the whole row header changing colors. Also, the region of detection should only be in the header column, whereas in the code you provided, when my cursor is in any place in the table, it changes color.
